# FullCalendar Custom/Override Header title

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want change the titleFormat of my calendar.

At present, the title is in an h2 tag and we cannot personalize it by adding html code to the titleFormat option. 
For example put a span tag on my fixed value of the titleFormat (which is [] there).

I would want to know if it is possible to override the updateTitle method of the class Header, without modifying fullcalendar.js. Or another possibility.

I have 2 views : week with title format '[Semaine] W' and custom one Day with title format 'dddd D MMMM YYYY'.

My version of FullCalendar is v2.3.0.

Comment: [`titleFormat`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/titleFormat/) should work fine, no? If you want to change what it looks like, use css.

Comment: Finaly, i use my own header. I wanted to have the title on several lines. 
(Semaine
W) For exemple
But as he(it) puts in H2, impossible to pass by the css.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, this isn't really supported but here's a workaround. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/owd804hd/3/)

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
    //The title isn't rendered until after this callback, so we need to use a timeout.
    if(view.type === "agendaWeek"){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("#calendar").find('.fc-toolbar > div > h2').empty().append(
                "<div>"+view.start.format('MMM Do [to]')+"</div>"+
                "<div>"+view.end.format('MMM Do')+"</div>"
            );
        },0);
    }else if(view.type === "agendaDay"){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("#calendar").find('.fc-toolbar > div > h2').empty().append(
                "<div>"+view.start.format('dddd D MMMM YYYY')+"</div>"
            );
        },0);
    }
},
```

I don't know if it's the most stable thing in the world but, at worst, it might have a slight aesthetic glitch sometimes (like when a new FC version gets released.).

Answer (score -4):

A simple way is to overwrite the **view.title** within the **viewRender** event:

```
...
,
header: {
  center: 'title',
},
viewRender: function(view, element) {
  view.title = 'Your Custom Title';
},
...
```

Comment: This did not work. Did you try this and see this actually working?

Comment: Yes it worked for me 3 years ago. Which version did you use? I can try this later with newest version of fullcalender too.

Comment: I was using the version that was used in the BookThatApp Shopify app. Looks like it's 3.4.0